# How to clone with proper branch options using wstool

Tags: ros, wstool, github, git

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using git, I can do:

`git clone --version indigo https://github.com/xxx` to get the correct branch from a particular repo. How can I achieve the same result using `wstool`?

[wstool wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/wstool)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252882/how-to-clone-with-proper-branch-options-using-wstool/) by [pallavbakshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28889/pallavbakshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2017-01-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest way is to create a [rosinstall file](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosinstall/html/rosinstall_file_format.html) and use the `version` tag. For your single example repository the `example.rosinstall` file would look like:

```
-git:
    uri: https://github.com/xxx
    local-name: yyy
    version: indigo
```

Note that the local name is typically just the repository name without the organization name, but you are free to organize your repositories into any structure you like (including subdirectories).

Once you have an `example.rosinstall` file you would add the repository to your workspace by going to the `src/` directory and using [wstool](http://wiki.ros.org/wstool#Merge_in_Additional_rosinstall_Files) to merge in additional rosinstall files:

```
wstool merge example.rosinstall
```

This will automatically populate the `.rosinstall` file in the `src/` directory of your workspace.

Another option (that is discouraged) is to manually edit the `.rosinstall` file in the `src/` directory of your workspace. However, that is an auto-generated file and your manual edits may be overwritten at a later time which can lead to confusion, which is why it is discouraged.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2017-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0